# GetAppendBlobReference is removed from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

What is the alternative to get an appendblob from a container?

Comment: Which client SDK version are you using? I checked Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 8.7, it still has this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your WindowsAzure.Storage version. As I test, the **version>= 5.0.2** of MicrosoftAzure Storage contains a definition for GetAppendBlobReference. You could follow the [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net).

> What is the alternative to get an appendblob from a container?

You could use Rest API to get the append blob. Append Block is supported only on version 2015-02-32 version or later.

For more detail, you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/append-block).

Answer (score 1):

Per the official documentation offered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getappendblobreference?view=azure-dotnet), it is supported and applied to the latest versions of Azure SDK and ,NET

This is a code example:

```
public virtual Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob GetAppendBlobReference (string blobName, Nullable<DateTimeOffset> snapshotTime);
```